# Using a field from influxdb as the title / label for a point on a grafana dashboard

Tags: influxdb, grafana

As the title suggests, I have a Grafana 'graph' that I populate with points from InfluxDB.  The elements of the time series have two fields: 'rate' and 'source'.  The graph is time on the x-axis of course, and 'rate' on the y-axis.  I'd like to see 'source' when I hover over a point.  Is this possible with Grafana / Infux?`

Answer (score -1):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, you should be able to use `aliasByNode` to achieve this.

Click on the metric editor, and you should be able to add it like in the example.

Here's the [example](http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/influxdb-annotations?panelId=2&fullscreen&edit&editorTab=Metrics)

Comment: For future visitors: this doesn't answer the question, as aliasByNode is a graphite option, not an influx one